# How to install NVIDIA Driver proprietary, tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

know anyone how can I install NVIDIA Driver proprietary, tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I've try different methods but no one of them don't work.

1. First them all I've try to install official Nvidia driver from http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/86390/en-us but after I've install it I don't know why but I cant login more on my Ubuntu, after I reboot my PC he enter Log mode... I use my password again and again but it don't want to enter...
2. The second method I've try add a new repository and I've used that commands in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
   ```

But after that sometime my screen freezing and if I enter in System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drives my Nvidia driver it's (open source) and I don't have the version for (proprietary) or (proprietary, tested).

So.. Does anyone know how I can install the Nvidia driver, but proprietary, not open source?

Here it's the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 178d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 139a (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 178d
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

And here are one photo with my Additional Drivers:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Order of preference of install is Ubuntu repository using System Settings, a ppa which has all the newest drivers and last and not really recommended -  directly from nVidia. But if you change driver install mode, you must purge all traces of previous nVidia driver or you get conflicts. You only need the very newest driver if you have very new nVidia chip or card. And old cards need to use legacy drivers, not any current driver or else issues.

Comment: why do you have to remove the repository st the end??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sudo have hybrid Intel+Nvidia graphics.

Your card is new and the recommended driver does not support it.

To install a working driver with adapter switcher run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot.

You will be able to switch adapters in Nvidia Settings application (PRIME profile).