# Screen Flicker in Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, screen, flicker

My Ubuntu PC's screen flickers every time I boot up. Sometimes, when it stops, it starts again when I move my mouse. My laptop has its own graphics card. Nvidia Geforce 8200m G.

Comment: Please see the answer to this topic

http://askubuntu.com/questions/650345/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-proprietary-tested-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: The issue is pretty likely your GPU. Being as it's likely pre-2010 it may have just burnt out over time. You might want to check to make sure you have the nvidia drivers installed from Additional Drivers first though.

Comment: Is it certain colors?  I noticed that the chrome incognito window triggers it when as little as 1 row of pixels from the little man's hat (upper left) is shown.  I had to get rid of my background too and go with the default Ubuntu screen (probably how they tested their code).

Comment: Another case, any page at https://en.wikipedia.org.  Simply scroll down and the screen flickering (or screen blackout) stops.  Scroll up about 1/2 into the Wikipedia logo and the screen goes crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing legacy drivers with nvidia settings

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-settings
```

That's what worked for me